# assembly: what is the return value exactly doing?

Tags: assembly

If I start a sub procedure on assembly, my stack-pointer %esp is aiming a
return value at the beginning.

1. how can I imagine it? What is the meaning of the return address?
2. is it just a pointer to an other address on the stack?
3. if it is an address and I do this commands at the beginning:

> ```
> mov %esp,%edi     # copy return address to %edi
> mov $0xff,%cl     # write 255 in %ecx (it was 0x0 before)
> mov %ecx,(%edi)   # copy 255 to... the stack point, the return
> ```
>
> address is aiming?
>                         # or just overwrite the return address?

Comment: Are you trying to learn assembly with a buffer overflow exploit as your first lesson? That's not going to go well.

Comment: Since you seem to be a new incarnation of user2469502, we can put the pieces together from your question history: you're trying out an exploit for an old version of openssl. If you're not blackhat, can you explain the situation, rather than continuing with minimal-context questions about small snippets of assembly code that you don't understand?

Comment: I created a new user because I reached the maximum of my posts. You are right, it's the slapper worm. I'm trying to understand how it works for my study in security management. It's really my first try in assembler. I understand that the register containing the values: %eax[102], %ebx[7] and %ecx[255] and the int 0x80 is executing the system call sys_socketcall(7,255), this should open a port or something, I still don't understand the parameter.... and I'm trying to draw what happens withe the stack and the register on my whiteboard...

Comment: I have the 8th stack-version now. I don't know if I'm right with my stack-painting, because I don't see a sense of all instructions. That's my situation ;-)

Comment: You should really learn assembly thoughtfully, and then reading such snippets. Otherwise you will keep bumping into stuff you don't understand - you asked at least several questions about single lines of assembly. This is not material for SO question, but for a good assembly manual.

Comment: And btw. "maximum of my posts". What is maximum of posts? The only thing that comes to my mind is too man questions without accepted answer (don't know if there is such a limit). If I'm right, perhaps you should think about why there are limits in the first place?

Comment: In the "full" code that was added in an edit, and has now been deleted in another edit, it appears to me that the caller's stack frame is being used as scratch space. This is possible because the exploit code doesn't intend to return. And it can't really be the full code because it just calls getpeername on fd 255

Answer (score 1):

1. On Intel, you're right that the return address is pushed to the stack before calling a function.
2. It is not an address to the stack, but the address of the instruction to return to once the function being called has completed.  For example, if you had a program that looked like this:

   ```
    instruction1
    instruction2
    call someFunction
    instruction3
    instruction4
   ```

   When `someFunction` completes, it will jump back and continue execution from `instruction3`.  It knows where to return to because the address of `instruction3` is pushed to the stack when the `call` instruction is executed.  `someFunction` will use the `ret` address to pop that address off the stack and return.
3. Your example overwrites the function's return address as you suggest - you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Ah, that means the return address in someFunction let me jump to instruction3, nice example! If I overwrite this address with the 255, is the creating a stackoverflow?

Comment: No, it's going to cause your program to start executing instructions from address 255.

Comment: the systemcall is socketcall and it's the last instruction of the shellcode, I', trying to understand. If I have overwritten the return address and the last instruction is my systemcall... what is happening after the systemcall? because I can't return to the next instruction... edit: you are fast ;-) ok, address 255? this isn't it nearly the end of the possible stack?

Comment: That's hard to say from your description.  Can you show more of the code in question?

Comment: I wonder... if %esp contains the ret addr at the beginning and I'm doing lea (%esp),%esi. Is the address I'm loading to %esp the address off my current %esp or the address, where the return address is aiming?

Comment: `esp` does not contain the return address.  The return address is on the stack.  Since `esp` is the stack pointer....